# h:commandLink not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, commandlink

I've created a simple JSF-Page with only one `<h:commandLink>` from the JSF HTML Library. Unfortunately the link is just shown as text and is therefore not clickable.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title><ui:insert name="title">Title</ui:insert></title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <div id="header"></div>

        <h:form id="form">
            <div id="content">
                <h:commandLink action="courseList">Courses</h:commandLink>
            </div>
        </h:form>

        <div id="footer">
            <ui:insert name="footer">
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </h:body>
```

I am just trying to add an simple link to the page "courseList". What can be the problem?

Comment: Make sure your XHTML template is all the way valid.

Comment: The problem was the XHTML template. You're right! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<h:commandLink action="courseList" value="Courses"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. Link is not visible at all.

Comment: Then probably the project isn't configured properly. I guess if you look at the page source of your first try, you'll see the `<h:commandLink ... >` source, which means the page isn't processed.